# MSXML2.DOMDocument load function fails in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been struggling with the below issue for a while now and couldn't find the solution yet.

There is an iShare page with an XML file that I want to download using VBA code, then later process the XML file and save into MS Access database.

I've been using the below code for about 4 years now, it worked perfectly without any issues. But suddenly it stopped working this week.
Any ideas why?

the code:

```
Private Function GetRequests() As Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Dim oDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim Url As String
  Dim sFileName As String

  Set oDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  oDoc.async = False
  Url = cUrlDatabase & "/" & cApplicationName & "/In/" & cReqXmlFile

  UpdateStatus "Loading " & cReqXmlFile

  If Not oDoc.Load(Url) Then
    c_sLastError = "Could not load XML " & Url
    GoTo EndProc
  End If

  sFileName = sPath & "\Data\requests.xml"

  oDoc.Save sFileName

  GetRequests = True
End Function
```

The code fails at the `oDoc.Load(Url)` part, it comes back false.

Comment: Hey John, did you find a solution? I'm struggeling with this too!

Comment: I figured out, that my xml document wasnt correct. I forgot to close a single tag <test id="123">... It had to be <test id="123></test>. Sadly the MSXML Library does not return what kind of error it recognizes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how to gather error details:

```
      Dim xDoc As MSXML.DOMDocument
      Set xDoc = New MSXML.DOMDocument

      If xDoc.Load("C:\My Documents\cds.xml") Then
        ' The document loaded successfully.

      Else
        ' The document failed to load.

        Dim strErrText As String
        Dim xPE As MSXML.IXMLDOMParseError

        ' Obtain the ParseError object
        Set xPE = xDoc.parseError
        With xPE
            strErrText = "Your XML Document failed to load" & _
            "due the following error." & vbCrLf & _
            "Error #: " & .errorCode & ": " & xPE.reason & _
            "Line #: " & .Line & vbCrLf & _
            "Line Position: " & .linepos & vbCrLf & _
            "Position In File: " & .filepos & vbCrLf & _
            "Source Text: " & .srcText & vbCrLf & _
            "Document URL: " & .url
        End With

        MsgBox strErrText, vbExclamation End If

        Set xPE = Nothing
      End If
```

[Example taken from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx#beginner_failure).

Comment: Excellent - thank-you.  Had to tweak it in my spreadsheet (Office 365), using the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library.  Needed to change the declaration of `MSXML.IXMLDOMParseError` to `MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError`.  Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

For other people finding this post:
The xml parser by now has implemented different error types (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
You would have to use the following code

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
ObjXML.async=true
objXML.load "/path/to/xml"
If objXML.parseError.errorCode <> 0 Then
   MsgBox "Error was " + objXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

This should help you debug your .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I found this error to be caused by text encoded in a format which could not be parsed in VBA (some weird E symbol). The objXML was nothing after the .load.  I'm sure there are many possible causes, but I'll share what I found in case this helps someone. Thanks to the guys above for the error handling routines.